# Passing two or more parameters from model view to controller in EF Core / ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, url, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I `_context.Controller.Remove(tbundle)` where tbundle is the following I get a successful delete from the table. My problem now is to pass the values for `NodeId` and `BundleId` from the delete button in the view.

```
BundleNode tbundle = _context.BundleNodes.Where(a => a.NodeId == 707955 && a.BundleId == 11).Single();
```

So I think I need to modify this line of code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
```

such that it will accept two parameters:

I tried this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int NodeId, int BundleId)
```

but it doesn't work. Maybe that is the correct syntax but I'm not sure how to structure the URL in the view such that the controller will consume it correctly.

The delete button code in the view is:

```html
<td style="text-align: center">
  <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="?n_id=@item.NodeId&b_id=@item.BundleId">
    <i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:red"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

When I hover over the delete button, the URL (bottom left) looks like this: "https://localhost:44324/BundleNodes/Delete/?n_id=739938&b_id=11" which is exactly what it's meant to look like. If I paste that URL into the browser then the n_id and b_id variables are populated correctly and everything works as it should. (FYI, if I right clock and copy the link and paste that into the browser it looks like this:"https://localhost:44324/BundleNodes/Delete/%3Fn_id%3D910699%26b_id%3D11).  If I click the delete button then both n_id and b_id are null and of course the delete fails because there is nothing to delete.

Comment: Do you want them to be Route parameters, Query parameters, or as part of a POSTed Request body?

Comment: Did you try using `HttpGet("nodes/{nodeId}/{bundleId}")`?

Comment: You have to post your view code with delete button

Comment: delete button code added with some further explanation.

Comment: @MaartenDev It is a post method and not a get method.  I'm trying to delete the record.  Apologies if that wasn't clear from the post.  If you read the post fully you'll see that the issue is passing the two parameters from the view to the controller.

Comment: @Dai I am trying to pass 2 parameters to a post method.  As I stated in my post, the URL 'hover preview' is exactly what it should be using asp-route-id="?n_id=@item.NodeId&b_id=@item.BundleId".  It's like something is happening to the URL when I click the delete button.  When I paste in the correct URL it works but if I click the button the variables are null.

Comment: @Serge.  I have posted the code with the delete button and a bit more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.  For the button in the view:

```html
@{
var link1 = Url.RouteUrl("twoids", new { controller = "BundleNodes", Action = "Delete", n_id = item.NodeId, b_id = item.BundleId });
}
<a href="@link1"> <i class="fas fa-trash" style="color:red"></i></a>
```

and a custom route in Program.cs

```html
app.MapControllerRoute(name: "twoids",
                pattern: "BundleNodes/Delete/{n_id}/{b_id}",                ,
                defaults: new { controller = "BundleNodes", action = "Delete"}
            );
```

Easy when you know how.